# FileSystemWatcher Events Untouchable by System.Delegate?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

I am writing integration tests that involve FileSystemWatcher objects.  To make things easier, I want to unsubscribe everything from an event delegate without having to hunt down every subscription.  I already saw related post, [Is it necessary to unsubscribe from events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963999/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-events).  This is somewhat a duplicate, but I am specifically asking why this doesn't work with a FileSystemWatcher object.

It would be nice to do something like the following:

```
private void MethodName()
{
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Temp");
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);

    watcher.Changed = null; // A simple solution that smells of C++.

    // A very C#-ish solution:
    foreach (FileSystemEventHandler eventDelegate in 
             watcher.Changed.GetInvocationList())
        watcher.Changed -= eventDelegate;
}
```

No matter how the Changed event is referenced, the compiler reports:
**The event 'System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Changed' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=**

The above code works just fine, when working with an event in the same class:

```
public event FileSystemEventHandler MyFileSystemEvent;

private void MethodName()
{
    MyFileSystemEvent += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);

    MyFileSystemEvent = null; // This works.

    // This works, too.
    foreach (FileSystemEventHandler eventDelegate in 
             MyFileSystemEvent.GetInvocationList())
        watcher.Changed -= eventDelegate;
}
```

So, what am I missing?  It seems that I should be able to do the same with the FileSystemWatcher events.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare event in your class, it is an equivalent (almost) of the following code:

```
private FileSystemEventHandler _eventBackingField;
public event FileSystemEventHandler MyFileSystemEvent
{
    add
    {
        _eventBackingField =
            (FileSystemEventHandler)Delegate.Combine(_eventBackingField, value);
    }
    remove
    {
        _eventBackingField =
            (FileSystemEventHandler)Delegate.Remove(_eventBackingField, value);
    }
}
```

Notice that there is no `set` or `get` accessor for event (like for properties) and you can't explicitly write them.

When you write `MyFileSystemEvent = null` in your class, it is actually doing `_eventBackingField = null`, but outside your class there is no way to directly set this variable, you have only event `add` & `remove` accessors.

This might be a confusing behavior, because inside your class you can reference an event handler delegate by event name, and can't do that outside the class.

Comment: Thanks for the 101 refresher course. I gotta step back from the tree, so I can see the whole forest. ;)

Comment: I see from your explanation that creating an extension will not help.  It would certainly be nice to be able to dump all subscriptions in one command.  I give this issue a solid "meh."

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is `+=` and `-=` are public operators while `=` is a private operator to the class that's declaring the event.