# simple custom event

Tags: c#, events

I'm trying to learn custom events and I have tried to create one but seems like I have a problem

I have created a Form, static class and custom event. What I'm trying to achieve is when I press button Form will call static class function and then func will from time to time rise an event to report current status. Form1 will listen if the event is raised and if it is, it will change Text of label1

Here is what I have so far

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public EventHandler<Progress> progress; 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        progress += SetStatus;
    }

    private void SetStatus(object sender, Progress e)
    {
        label1.Text = e.Status;
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         TestClass.Func();
    }

 }
```

File 2

```
class TestClass
{
    public static void Func()
    {
        //time consuming code
        Report status 
        // time consuming code
        report status
    }
}

public class Progress : EventArgs
{
    public string Status { get; private set; }

    private Progress() {}

    public Progress(string status)
    {
        Status = status;
    }
}
```

Now what I don't understand is, how can I rise an event from TestClass so Form1 can handle event and change label.Text

Comment: Your TestClass will have to provide an event and the Form will have to subscribe to it.

Comment: yep, that's fine but I dont understand how can I rise an event from another class

Answer (score 149, accepted):

This is an easy way to create custom events and raise them. You create a delegate and an event in the class you are throwing from. Then subscribe to the event from another part of your code. You have already got a custom event argument class so you can build on that to make other event argument classes. N.B: I have not compiled this code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private TestClass _testClass;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _testClass = new TestClass();
        _testClass.OnUpdateStatus += new TestClass.StatusUpdateHandler(UpdateStatus);
    }

    private void UpdateStatus(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        SetStatus(e.Status);
    }

    private void SetStatus(string status)
    {
        label1.Text = status;
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         TestClass.Func();
    }

}

public class TestClass
{
    public delegate void StatusUpdateHandler(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e);
    public event StatusUpdateHandler OnUpdateStatus;

    public static void Func()
    {
        //time consuming code
        UpdateStatus(status);
        // time consuming code
        UpdateStatus(status);
    }

    private void UpdateStatus(string status)
    {
        // Make sure someone is listening to event
        if (OnUpdateStatus == null) return;

        ProgressEventArgs args = new ProgressEventArgs(status);
        OnUpdateStatus(this, args);
    }
}

public class ProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Status { get; private set; }

    public ProgressEventArgs(string status)
    {
        Status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another important point to events is talked about in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963999/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-events). To unsubscribe from events, it is -= instead of the +=. 

For example _testClass.OnUpdateStatus -= UpdateStatus;

Where to place the unsubscribing code is another question, but there are other stack overflow questions that deal with that.

Comment: A poor choice of names. Both classes have an `UpdateStatus` function which can be confusing. I'd rather call the function in `Form1` with a different name like `ProcessUpdateStatusEvent` for clarity.
Otherwise very good explanation.

Comment: The readonly attribute on the ProgressEventArgs does not compile.  Removing this attribute and this works beautifully.

Comment: This code is more confusing than necessary and not thread safe. Check out this explanation https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/ and the answer from @Volomike.

Comment: As written, `TestClass.UpdateStatus()` cannot be called from `static void Func()`. The `static` modifier must be removed from `Func()`.  Then, the `button1_Click_1` needs to be changed to call `_testClass.Func()` instead of the static method.  After that, this solution will work.  However, the call to `_testClass.Func()` will be blocking, so the only update you'll see is the last status update that was called before `_testClass.Func()` returns. In order to get the label to update while `Func()` runs in the background, you need to run it asynchronously.  See my update to this answer below...

Answer (score 21):

You haven't created an event. To do that write:

```
public event EventHandler<Progress> Progress;
```

Then, you can call `Progress` from within the class where it was declared like normal function or delegate:

```
Progress(this, new Progress("some status"));
```

So, if you want to report progress in `TestClass`, the event should be in there too and it should be also static. You can the subscribe to it from your form like this:

```
TestClass.Progress += SetStatus;
```

Also, you should probably rename `Progress` to `ProgressEventArgs`, so that it's clear what it is.

Answer (score 19):

Events are pretty easy in C#, but the MSDN docs in my opinion make them pretty confusing. Normally, most documentation you see discusses making a class inherit from the `EventArgs` base class and there's **[a reason](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2011/11/29/eventhandler-or-action/)** for that. However, it's not the simplest way to make events, and for someone wanting something quick and easy, and in a time crunch, using the `Action` type is your ticket.

#### Creating Events & Subscribing To Them

1. Create your event in your class right after your `class` declaration.

```
public event Action<string,string,string,string>MyEvent;
```

2. Create your event handler class method in your class.

```
private void MyEventHandler(string s1,string s2,string s3,string s4)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}",s1,s2,s3,s4);
}
```

3. Now when your class is invoked, tell it to connect the event to your new event handler. The reason the `+=` operator is used is because you are appending your particular event handler to the event. You can actually do this with multiple separate event handlers, and when an event is raised, each event handler will operate in the sequence in which you added them.

```
class Example
{
  public Example() // I'm a C# style class constructor
  {
    MyEvent += new Action<string,string,string,string>(MyEventHandler);
  }
}
```

4. Now, when you're ready, trigger (aka raise) the event somewhere in your class code like so:

```
MyEvent("wow","this","is","cool");
```

The end result when you run this is that the console will emit "wow this is cool". And if you changed "cool" with a date or a sequence, and ran this event trigger multiple times, you'd see the result come out in a FIFO sequence like events should normally operate.

In this example, I passed 4 strings. But you could change those to any kind of acceptable type, or used more or less types, or even remove the `<...>` out and pass nothing to your event handler.

And, again, if you had multiple custom event handlers, and subscribed them all to your event with the `+=` operator, then your event trigger would have called them all in sequence.

#### Identifying Event Callers

But what if you want to identify the caller to this event in your event handler? This is useful if you want an event handler that reacts with conditions based on who's raised/triggered the event. There are a few ways to do this. Below are examples that are shown in order by how fast they operate:

Option 1. (Fastest) If you already know it, then pass the name as a literal string to the event handler when you trigger it.

Option 2. (Somewhat Fast) Add this into your class and call it from the calling method, and then pass that string to the event handler when you trigger it:

```
private static string GetCaller([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string s = null) => s;
```

Option 3. (Least Fast But Still Fast) In your event handler when you trigger it, get the calling method name string with this:

```
string callingMethod = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().ReflectedType.Name.Split('<', '>')[1];
```

#### Unsubscribing From Events

You may have a scenario where your custom event has multiple event handlers, but you want to remove one special one out of the list of event handlers. To do so, use the `-=` operator like so:

```
MyEvent -= MyEventHandler;
```

A word of minor caution with this, however. If you do this and that event no longer has any event handlers, and you trigger that event again, it will throw an exception. (Exceptions, of course, you can trap with try/catch blocks.)

#### Clearing All Events

Okay, let's say you're through with events and you don't want to process any more. Just set it to null like so:

```
MyEvent = null;
```

The same caution for Unsubscribing events is here, as well. If your custom event handler no longer has any events, and you trigger it again, your program will throw an exception.

Comment: As someone who is searching for the "quick and easy" solution, this answer is what I hoped to find.

Comment: When you say "create your event ON you class", do you mean "...IN your class"?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Like has been mentioned already the progress field needs the keyword event

```
public event EventHandler<Progress> progress;
```

But I don't think that's where you actually want your event. I think you actually want the event in `TestClass`. How does the following look? (I've never actually tried setting up static events so I'm not sure if the following will compile or not, but I think this gives you an idea of the pattern you should be aiming for.)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TestClass.progress += SetStatus;
    }

    private void SetStatus(object sender, Progress e)
    {
        label1.Text = e.Status;
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         TestClass.Func();
    }

 }

public class TestClass
{
    public static event EventHandler<Progress> progress; 

    public static void Func()
    {
        //time consuming code
        OnProgress(new Progress("current status"));
        // time consuming code
        OnProgress(new Progress("some new status"));            
    }

    private static void OnProgress(EventArgs e) 
    {
       if (progress != null)
          progress(this, e);
    }
}


public class Progress : EventArgs
{
    public string Status { get; private set; }

    private Progress() {}

    public Progress(string status)
    {
        Status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work.  The call to `progress(this, e)` requires an instance of the class in order to have a `this` to pass in.  You must remove all of the `static` modifiers and create an instance of `TestClass` within `Form1` and reference that object instead of the static methods. After that, it works, but only when the operations in `Func()` are not blocking.  In order to get the label to update while `Func()` runs in the background, you need to run it asynchronously. See my update to this answer below...

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite a bit of time researching how to achieve this for my own purposes and found my answers scattered throughout a number of sources. I will try to apply what I've learned, to the OP's question and then expand beyond that to address asynchronous requirements.

### Answering the Original Question

1. As others suggested, move your `EventHandler` to `TestClass`...

```
public class TestClass
{
    public event EventHandler<Progress> progress;
    ...
}
```

...then create an instance of `TestClass` in `Form1` and subscribe to it's event...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private TestClass _testClass;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _testClass = new TestClass();
        _testClass.progress += SetStatus;
    }
    ...
}
```

2. Change `button1_Click_1` to reference the internal object instead of the `static` method...

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _testClass.Func();
}
```

3. Remove all `static` modifiers from methods and properties of `TestClass`.
4. Change the `Func()` method to include some valid code for testing...

```
public void Func()
{
    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // Sleep for 2 seconds
        progress?.Invoke(this, new Progress("Iteration " + i + " complete..."));
    }
}
```

> NOTE: C#6 added the `?` token, so there is no need to check and see if there are any subscribers to the event. There is also no need to create a delegate, making the code more complex.  You can simply `Invoke` the event, to raise it up to all subscribers.

This will get your form working. However, `Func()` will be blocking, so the only status update you will see, will be the last status message. I'm assuming the OP wanted the form to remain unblocked, so periodic status updates would be displayed to the user.

### Asynchronus Execution

If you truly want `Func()` to run in the background, you need to make that call asynchronously.  To do that, complete the following additional steps.

1. Add the `async` modifier to `button_Click_1` and call `Func()` using `Task.Run`...

```
private async void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _testClass.Func();
    });
}
```

2. Since the event will be raised by a background task, you must modify `SetStatus()` to `Invoke` the setting of `label1.Text` on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

```
private void SetStatus(object sender, Progress e)
{
    if (label1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            label1.Text = e.Status;
        }));
    } else
    {
        label1.Text = e.Status;
    }
}
```

3. Now that `Func()` is executing asynchronously, you'll notice that you can resize and interact with the form while `Func()` is executing in the background.  That means you could also click button1 again and kick off a second instance of `Func()` in the background.

   To prevent that, you can modify `button1_Click_1`, to disable the button until `Func()` completes. I chose to save the button text and change it to "Processing...", then restore the original button text when `Func()` is finished.

```
private async void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var savedText = button1.Text;
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button1.Text = "Processing...";

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _testClass.Func();
    });

    button1.Text = savedText;
    button1.Enabled = true; 
}
```

### Cancelling the Asynchronous Task

Now that you have your task running in the background, you may find you have the need to cancel that background task.  For that, you need to pass a cancellation token into the `Func()` method and check on it periodically, exiting the method prematurely, when requested.

1. Create a private cancellation token in `Form1`...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private CancellationTokenSource funcCancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
...
}
```

2. Pass a new cancellation token into `Func()`, each time it is called.

```
    funcCancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _testClass.Func(funcCancellationToken);
    });
```

3. check the token periodically within `Func()`, to determine if the process should be aborted.

```
public void Func(CancellationTokenSource cancelToken)
{
    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            progress?.Invoke(this, new Progress("Process canceled after " + (i - 1) + " iterations"));
            break;
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // Sleep for 2 seconds
        progress?.Invoke(this, new Progress("Iteration " + i + " complete..."));
    }
}
```

> NOTE: There is also a `TaskCanceledException()` that you can throw, then catch from `button1_Click_1`, if you want more detailed information about the state of the process when it was canceled.

4. Choose a method for the user to request the cancellation of the background task. For this example, I chose to use `button1` to start ****and**** cancel the background task. It makes the code a little more complex, but the user experience is better (in my opinion). I modified `button1_Click_1` as follows...

```
private async void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string savedText = button1.Text;

    if (button1.Text == "Cancel")
    {
        button1.Text = "Cancelling...";
        button1.Enabled = false;
        funcCancellationToken.Cancel();
    } else
    {
        savedText = button1.Text;
        button1.Text = "Cancel";
        funcCancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _testClass.Func(funcCancellationToken);
        });

        button1.Enabled = true;
        button1.Text = savedText;
    }
}
```

### Final Result

Now that I've explained the iterative process I used to get to a final result that I was happy with in my own project, I'll provide the full source of the final asynchronous implementation.  Please note that I renamed the `Progress` type to `ProgressEventArgs`, the `progress` event to `OnProgressUpdated`, and `button1_Click_1` to `button1_Click_1Async`, to align the code with common naming conventions.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private CancellationTokenSource funcCancellationToken;
    private TestClass _testClass;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _testClass = new TestClass();
        _testClass.OnProgressUpdated += SetStatus;
    }

    private void SetStatus(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (label1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                label1.Text = e.Status;
            }));
        } else
        {
            label1.Text = e.Status;
        }
    }

    private async void button1_Click_1Async(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string savedText = button1.Text;

        if (button1.Text == "Cancel")
        {
            button1.Text = "Cancelling...";
            button1.Enabled = false;
            funcCancellationToken.Cancel();
        } else
        {
            savedText = button1.Text;
            button1.Text = "Cancel";
            funcCancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _testClass.Func(funcCancellationToken);
            });

            button1.Enabled = true;
            button1.Text = savedText;
        }
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public event EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs> OnProgressUpdated;

    public void Func(CancellationTokenSource cancelToken)
    {
        for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                OnProgressUpdated?.Invoke(this, new ProgressEventArgs("Process canceled after " + (i - 1) + " iterations"));
                break;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // Sleep for 2 seconds
            OnProgressUpdated?.Invoke(this, new ProgressEventArgs("Iteration " + i + " complete..."));
        }
    }
}

public class ProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Status { get; private set; }

    private ProgressEventArgs() { }

    public ProgressEventArgs(string status)
    {
        Status = status;
    }
}
```