# Passing Mouseclick events to controls con

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, event-handling

I have a custom control `DigitalPanel` that has a FlowLayoutPanel(`viewPanel`), which is filled with custom controls (`DigitalIndicator`). When a user clicks on a `DigitalIndicator` within the `viewPanel` I would like to notify `DigitalPanel` of this event. Currently I watch for `viewPanel`'s onMouseClick event, but this is only triggered when the spaces between the `DigitialIndicators` is clicked and not when they are click on themselves.

So from what I have gathered on Stack Overflow is that I need to get the `onMouseClick` event from each `DigitalIndicator` before I add it to the `viewPanel` and watch for these events from/in the `viewPanel`'s `onMouseClick` event.

So then if a `DigitalIndicator` is clicked, it will raise the event, `viewPanel` will see that and in turn raise its `onMouseClick` event which the `DigitalPanel` will see and handle?

My issues is I am not sure how to get the `DigitalIndicator`'s `onMouseClick` event from it. Here is what I have.

// This is from the `DigitalPanel` class when a new `DigitalIndicator` is being added

```
DigitalIndicatior newDigInd= new DigitalIndicatior();
this.viewPanel.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(newDigInd.);
```

I am not sure what the arguments to the `MouseEventHandler` should be exactly. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can define event in the viewPanel, then you can do the following

- Declare an Event in viewPanel (DigitalIndicatorClicked)
- When DigitalIndicator is clicked, its Click event will raise viewPanel's event DigitalIndicatorClicked, passing the sender (DigitalIndicator) as sender to this raised event
- Your DigitalPanel will handle the DigitalIndicatorClicked event of the ViewPanel. This event handler will also receive the original DigitalIndicator object as sender (passed in above step)

Comment: Something like the first answer to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644247/simple-custom-event

Comment: Yup (y). The only this is that this answer shows you how to declare and raise event (defined in viewPanel) from DigitalIndicator object. You have to add another level to it where viewPanel can raise event declared in DigitalPanel

Comment: Is there an easier way then declaring my own events. I cannot do it with the predefined OnMouseClick event(s)?

Comment: You can raise the `OnMouseClick` event of viewPanel from the `DigitalIndicator_OnMouseClick` event handler by writing the line `OnMouseClick(sender, e)` and handle that event in DigitalPanel (`viewPanel_OnMouseClick` event handler)