# RaiseEvent on C sharp

Tags: c#, class, events, raise, raiseevent

I know there is a lot of information about RaiseEvents on internet, but I can't understand them, somebody can help me with a simple example on C#.

Thanks very much.

Comment: You need to be much more specific. What part exactly is giving you a problem. StackOverflow isn't a grinds website.

Comment: @judgeja - even as someone from the UK I had to look up the meaning of "grinds" in that context.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644247/simple-custom-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this in your class

```
public event EventHandler<string> MessageHasSent;
public void SendMessage(string message)
{
    EventHandler<string> ms =  MessageHasSent;
    if (ms!= null)
    {
         ms(this,message);
    }
}
```

And in every where in your class that you want Raise this event. For example this will raise event when an error occurred

```
try
{
}
catch ( Exception ex)
{
    SendMessage("error occurred :"+ex.Message);
}
```

And use it like other events

Comment: Past tense of Send = Sent, not Sended.