# How to send notification with mouse/key hook data from C# dll to wpf exe

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, keyboard-hook, mouse-hook

I am creating a C# WPF exe and a C# DLL. There is a function called StartRecording in DLL. The exe calls this function. The function installs Low-level mouse and keyboard hooks on a third party application (e.g. MS Word). Inside the hook procedures, I collect details related to the mouse/keyboard message and also the details of the control (using UI Automation) with which the user interacts.

I want to send a notification from the DLL to the exe that data have been collected and in the notification itself, I want to send the data. What is the best way to do this? One option, I can think of is to send WM_COPY_DATA message from the dll to the exe. But is there any better way? Is there a way by which I can send a Dictionary from the dll to the exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two of many solutions to this:

**First:**
You could implement an `event handler` and register your `ViewModel` at your dll-class. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644247/simple-custom-event) - to implement your own custom event - if even  needed.

**Second:**
Or you go with an `interface` if you only have one instance to listen.

```
public interface IListen
{
    void SendMessage(string msg);

    void SendDictonary(IDictionary<object, object> dic);
}


public class MyDllClass
{
    public IListen Listener
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void SomeMouseInputAppears()
    {
        if(Listener != null) Listener.SendMessage("sample");
    }

    public void SomeKeyboardInputAppears()
    {
        if (Listener != null) Listener.SendDictonary(new Dictionary<object,object>());
    }
}
```

Of course the `interface` is in your `dll` and the implementation of it has to be in the view library / application.

Comment: Thank you. I used the second solution, creating my own interface. This way I can decide names of methods, number of methods and number and types of arguments.

Comment: I prefer this too mate