# ToolStripTextBox delay TextChanged

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I need to retrieve the `TextChanged` event of the `ToolStripTextBox` with a delay, to do some stuff after x seconds of stop keypressing..

I found this (and works) example for the `TextBox`.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20068/Custom-TextBox-that-Delays-the-TextChanged-Event

I tried to convert it for the `ToolStripTextBox`, but I got this error:

```
void DelayTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // stop timer.
    DelayTimer.Enabled = false;

    // set timer elapsed to true, so the OnTextChange knows to fire
    TimerElapsed = true;

    try
    {
        // use invoke to get back on the UI thread.
        this.Invoke(new DelayOverHandler(DelayOver), null);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

> 'DelayToolStripTextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Invoke' and
>   no extension method 'Invoke' accepting a first argument of type
>   'DelayToolStripTextBox' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

the `ToolStripTextBox` doesn't have the 'Invoke` method..

does anybody can help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: To change the linked article to `ToolStripTextBox`, you can do either of following options: **1)** Use a `System.WIndows.Forms.Timer` instead of `System.Timers.Timer` which is used in the article and use its `Tick` event. Then you don't need to use Invoke. Just call the method directly. The reason of using `Invoke` in the article is, because `Elapse` event will raise on a different thread than UI thread and you need to use `Invoke` to interact with UI thread. **2)** **Or** use `this.TextBox.Invoke` instead of `this.Invoke`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use some external code? A timer will do your work easily:

Define a `Timer`, which will be started when the `TextChange`s. If the `Timer` is running, it should be resettet.
If `Timer.Intervall` is reached, we know that we got no new input, because the timmer was not reset.
Now the `Timer` should trigger its `Tick`-event. The event should fire our method, which we bound to it with `t.Tick += ClearText;`.

```
// your trigger
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartEventAfterXSeconds();
}

private Timer t;

// your time-management
private void StartEventAfterXSeconds(int seconds = 10)
{
    if (t != null)
    {
        t.Stop();
    }
    else
    {
        t = new Timer();
        t.Tick += ClearText;
    }

    t.Interval = 1000 * seconds;
    t.Start();
}

// You action
public void ClearText(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    this.textBox1.Text = null;
    t.Stop();
}
```

If you want to use multiple of these TextBoxes you should move everything to a class.

1. Inherit the Textbox
2. Add an Event which should be fired *after* the delay.
3. Build a method which starts the timer and is fired by the normal `TextChanged`-event
4. Implement the Tick-Method which fires your new event and stops the timer.

Some Info about custom-events without the timer with it's tick-method: [simple custom event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644247/simple-custom-event)

```
public class TextBoxWithDelay : TextBox
{
    public TextBoxWithDelay()
    {
        this.DelayInSeconds = 10;

        this.TextChanged += OnTextChangedWaitForDelay;
    }

    public int DelayInSeconds { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler TextChangedWaitForDelay;

    private Timer t;
    private void OnTextChangedWaitForDelay(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (t != null)
        {
            t.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            t = new Timer();
            t.Tick += DoIt;
        }

        t.Interval = 1000 * DelayInSeconds;
        t.Start();
    }

    public void DoIt(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (TextChangedWaitForDelay != null)
        {
            TextChangedWaitForDelay.Invoke(sender, args);
            t.Stop();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I wish have the code inside my derived class, to be used in different components

Comment: thanks @kara ! it worked!! but I have a question.. when you do `t.Tick += DoIt;` why it works (correctly) once and not each time he's changed?

Comment: `TextChanged`-Event triggers `OnTextChangedWaitForDelay`. `OnTextChangedWaitForDelay` starts or resets (if running) the timer. when the timer ticks, your method bound to the `TextChangedWaitForDelay`-Event will be invoked.
The `DoIt`is bound to the event `Timer.Tick` which is fired every `Interval`. The "magic" is, that the timer is stopped when it fired one tick.

Comment: Your code is also an external code! So we cannot say *Why do you use some external code?* :)

Comment: Yup - Now with this class it's some sort of extern. The intention of the 1st block was to show the mechanics with a timer. The 2nd block is that result you get, after understanding the 1st one.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a solution similar to your situation. I know how to do this in Javascript using setTimeout (debounce), so I set out to do something similar in C# via Tasks. Here's what I came up with:

```
private Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource> DebounceActions = new Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource>();

private void Debounce(string key, int millisecondsDelay, Action action)
{
    if (DebounceActions.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        DebounceActions[key].Cancel();
    }
    DebounceActions[key] = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = DebounceActions[key].Token;
    Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay, token).ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        else
        {
            action();
        }
    }, token);
}
```

Just pass it a unique `key` to identify which method it's calling from.