# Remove event listener from local variable

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, event-listener

Do I have to worry about removing event listeners assigned to local variables?

Consider the following sample:

```
var zipUtil = new ZipUtil();
zipUtil.ProgressChanged += ZipUtil_ProgressChanged;
```

I'm creating an instance of the `ZipUtil` class which is stored as a local variable within a method. Do I have to remove the listener (`zipUtil.ProgressChanged -= ZipUtil_ProgressChanged;`) before the method terminates or is it okay to skip the step?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it necessary to unsubscribe from events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963999/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-events)

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Almost, but not quite, with this one particularly referring to local variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't have to remove that event handling method.

When adding an event handler to an event, a reference from the (object containing the) event to the event handler is created, not the other way round. Once `zipUtil` goes out of scope, the event handler will not make any difference pertaining to references to `zipUtil`.

Comment: I suppose the same logic applies if I run the method multiple times, right? (Thank you for the answer, it will let me validate it in 7 minutes).

Comment: @IneedHelp: Do you mean the method the code quoted in your question is part of? Yes, you'll create a new `ZipUtil` instance every time, and once that local `zipUtil` variable goes out of scope, that instance disappears every time (unless you have added another reference to it somewhere in your method, that is).

Answer (score 2):

Two lines of code are never enough to make the call accurately.  But it is very unlikely you'll need to unsubscribe explicitly.  There are two possible problem scenarios:

- the class may fire its event at an inopportune time, after your object is disposed for example.  That's fairly unlikely in this scenario, surely the ZipUtil class stops raising ProgressChanged events when you stop calling its methods.  Not *completely* out of the question, it could do work on a background thread for example.  Not visible from your snippet.
- you can have a garbage collection problem due to events.  The event delegate keeps an implicit reference to your class object, necessary so it can call ZipUtil_ProgressChanged() method.  If it is an instance method, not clear from your snippet.  That reference will keep your outer class alive.  But not the other way around.  Given that the lifetime of the ZipUtil object is restricted to the method and you surely want your outer class to survive at least to the end of the method, this should never be a problem.

High odds that ZipUtil implements IDisposable btw.  Do make sure you use the *using* statement if it does.

Comment: I have extracted those two lines from a background worker `DoWork` method. They are followed by code which creates zip archives based on different settings. The `ZipUtil` class doesn't implement `IDisposable`. My dilemma was whether I had to remove the listener or not at the end of the background worker's `DoWork` method, regardless of using the worker once or multiple times. I learned here that I do not have to. Thank you the information you provided. +1